# $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod n$ and $a\not\equiv \pm b\pmod n\implies\gcd(a+b,n)$ is a factor of $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod n $ and that $a\not\equiv \pm b\pmod n$. How to then show that $\gcd(a+b,n)$ is a (nontrivial) factor of $n$?

Hint to get started please.

Comment: It's obviously a factor of $n$, right? If it equaled $n$, what would that say about the congruences in the hypotheses?

Comment: I'm a bit new to number theory. I'm afraid I don't see why its obvious. May you elaborate a little if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: Hint:  $a^2=b^2 \pmod n\implies a^2-b^2=0\pmod n\implies (a+b)(a-b)=0\pmod n$.

Comment: The greatest common *divisor* of $x$ and $y$ is, in particular, a divisor of $x$ and a divisor of $y$.

Comment: $\gcd(m,n)$ is always a divisor of $n$.

Comment: @GregMartin: Ah, of course. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the following fact?

> If $n|xy$ and $gcd(n,x) = 1$ then $n | y$.

In the present context, $n|(a^2 - b^2)$ and $gcd(a+b,n) = 1$ would imply $n|(a-b)$.

Clearly $gcd(a+b,n)$ is a divisor of $n$. In light of these comments can it equal $1$?

Comment: The "fact" follows from either unique factorization or Bezout's lemma.